Is this tuning fork forever?
Imagine a tuning fork struck in the Boötes Void. At first, the phonons convert to friction \ heat and radiate off into blackbody photons. This happens for a long time, and then at some point, we reach the CMB temperature, where incoming heat and outgoing heat equalize, thus increasing the infrequency of converting phonons to heat as the phonon energy degenerates.
Would the tuning fork ring in perpetuity? Would the "temperature" eventually overwhelm the original strike, altogether canceling its effects?  Even with decreasing CMB energy over cosmological scales of time, would it really stop?

A tuning fork on earth reaches equilibrium with the surroundings at a higher temperature. Even without air friction, vibrations decay. Internal molecular motion never stops, but I wouldn't call it ringing.
Your tuning fork would be much the same.
